# Loop Nested JSON in HTML Table with Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I Have a Problem finding way to loop data,
I Have Json Data Like This

```
[
 {
  "STATUS":"CUTTING INHOUSE",
  "STID":"1",
  "CATS":[
     {
        "CAT":"ORIGINALS ",
        "ARTS":[
           {
              "ARTNO":"GY8252",
              "QTY":"3.0"
           },
           {
              "ARTNO":"GY8255",
              "QTY":"23.0"
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        "CAT":"RUNNING",
        "ARTS":[
           {
              "ARTNO":"GW8588",
              "QTY":"3.0"
           },
           {
              "ARTNO":"GW8589",
              "QTY":"45.0"
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
},
{
  "STATUS":"CUTTING SUBCONT",
  "STID":"2",
  "CATS":[
     {
        "CAT":"ORIGINALS ",
        "ARTS":[
           {
              "ARTNO":"GY8252",
              "QTY":"46.0"
           },
           {
              "ARTNO":"GY8255",
              "QTY":"32.0"
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        "CAT":"RUNNING",
        "ARTS":[
           {
              "ARTNO":"GW8588",
              "QTY":"52.0"
           },
           {
              "ARTNO":"GW8589",
              "QTY":"52.0"
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
 },
]
```

So I Want to Show it on Table

```html
<tbody v-for="i in repdata" :key="i.STID">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" class="stephead" colspan="6">{{ i.STATUS }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="j in i.CATS" :key="j.CAT">
    <td>ASDSAD</td>
    <td>{{ j.CAT }}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>3T</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>SMS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="totbycat">
    <td colspan="4">Total Qty:</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="grandtot">
    <td colspan="4">Grand Total Cutting :</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The Result from my code is still wrong
[image: Current Result]

I cannot Loop ARTS
My Expectation Output is Like
[image: My Exspectation Output]

I Have try add div before tr but it doesn't work, as I know we cannot put
except    in table,

please i have confuse to looking for solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 fundamental difficulties implementing your request:

1. While you want to show subtotal per category, you don't have one in the original data, and you need to somehow process the original data into a new one. Use `computed` property for this purpose.
2. You could define a bunch of `colspan` to show the desired result, but it can be ridiculously complicated. Simply use `div` with set width for each cell.

Here is a sample implementation in CodePen:
https://codepen.io/mina-tokyo/pen/mdOLxyV